# Wikipedia's likelihood function of tobit model

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, likelihood, tobit-regression

[image]

This is the likelihood of the [tobit model on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobit_model). To my understanding, the first is the normal density when y is greater than the threshold and the second is the cdf of y for everything below the threshold. I had two questions about this.

1. Why is the normal pdf $\phi$ multiplied by $\frac 1 \sigma$? Why not just the normal pdf? Is it a scaling factor or something?
2. Conceptually, it seems like we are mixing pdfs (densities) and cdfs (probabilities). Is it because of the $\frac 1 \sigma$ that this makes any sense?

Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I understand the Tobit model, you either observe $y_i$ when $y_i>0$ or the fact that $y_i<0$ but not the precise value of $y_i\sim\mathcal N(x_i'\beta,\sigma^2)$. (This means $y_L=0$ in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobit_model).) Thus, the distribution of the data, made of the $$y_i\mathbb I_{y_i>0}\qquad i=1,\ldots,n$$is mixed, with a continuous component when $y>0$ and a point mass at $0$ when $y=0$. The density of $y_i$ with respect to this mixed measure (Lebesgue plus point mass at zero) is thus
$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{\sigma}\varphi(\sigma^{-1}\{y_i-x_i'\beta\})}_{\text{exact Normal pdf}\\\text{ for }y_i\sim\mathcal N(x_i'\beta,\sigma^2)}\underbrace{\mathbb{I}_{y_i>0}}_{I(y_i)}+
\underbrace{\Phi(-\sigma^{-1}x_i'\beta)}_{\mathbb P_{\beta,\sigma}(Y_i<0)|X_i)}\mathbb{I}_{y_i=0}$$
The fraction in $\sigma$ is a component of the $\mathcal N(x_i'\beta,\sigma^2)$ density (as $\varphi$ corresponds to the standard Normal distribution).

Comment: Fantastic answer! +1